# Powershell output format

Tags: powershell

I am making a powershell object as follows :

```
$innerObj = New-Object PSObject

$innerObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Arr" -Value @(1,2,3)

$outerObj = New-Object PSObject

$outerObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Outer" -Value $innerObj
```

Now when I print $outerObj using Write-Output (Piping to Format-List), it shows me this :

```
outer : @{arr=System.Object[]}
```

Why is it showing System.Object[]. I can see the elements of array when I do $outerObj.outer but I want to print the whole object as such without this System.Object[]. How can I do this? Should this be something other than an array? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't override the toString method to display the contents?

Comment: What do you mean by overriding that method in Powershell? If you are talking about converting array to string, then I cannot do that because I will not be able to index the array in that case.

Comment: You have a typo on your last line that makes your example not work - `-Value $inner` should be `-Value $innerObj`

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it with a custom format:

```
$innerFormat = @{Name="inner";Expression={$_.outer.Arr}}
$outerObj | select $innerFormat  | fl

inner : {1, 2, 3}

or
$outerObj | fl $innerFormat
```

But I don't know if that's the *right* way or if there's some better way.